# Table of content margin

Tags: table-of-contents, margins

According to the below the figure, how can i adjust the margin of table of content according to the red line [image]

```
\usepackage[titles]{tocloft}
\renewcommand{\cftchapleader}{\cftdotfill{\cftdotsep}}
\renewcommand{\cftchapfont}{\mdseries}
\renewcommand{\cftchappagefont}{\mdseries}
\renewcommand\cftsecdotsep{\cftdot}
\renewcommand\cftsubsecdotsep{\cftdot}
\renewcommand{\cftchapleader}{\cftdotfill{\cftsecdotsep}}
```

Comment: [Welcome to TeX.SE](http://meta.tex.stackexchange.com/questions/1436). You can have a look at our [starter guide](http://meta.tex.stackexchange.com/q/1436) to familiarize yourself further with our format.

Comment: It would be helpful if you took the code in the linked question and added your own text to yield a fully compilable [MWE](http://meta.tex.stackexchange.com/questions/228) including `\documentclass{}` (`\begin{document}` and `\end{document}`) and the appropriate packages that *illustrates* the problem . While solving problems can be fun, setting them up is not. Then, those trying to help can simply cut and paste your MWE and get started on solving the problem, instead of spending time to first reproduce the problem.

Comment: Later that day [Table of content problem](http://tex.stackexchange.com/q/196930) was posted, seems like the OP solved the problem. As this Q is unclear without some working code, i am voting to close as unclear.