# Table of content problem

Tags: table-of-contents, titletoc

I have prepared table of contents for my thesis like that[image]

But our university wants like that

[image]

The main difference between them,
In the second screenshot, chapter and section heading numbers are bold and also contains dot
for example

> **1.** INTRODUCTION

I have used to prepare table of content for chapter this code blocks

```
\titlecontents{chapter}
[25pt]         % left margin
{}%
{\contentsmargin{10pt}         % numbered entry format
    \thecontentslabel\enspace%
    \normalfont }
{\contentsmargin{10pt}\normalfont}      % unnumbered entry format
{\titlerule*[1mm]{.}\contentspage}                 % filler-page format (e.g dots)
[]
```

Comment: Is the flush-left vs flush-right alignment of the page numbers important?

Comment: Welcome to TeX.SX! Please show us a complete but minimal working document which yields your first picture. Like this, we do not have to type everything for you.

Comment: alignment not important for me

Comment: \newcommand{\tocpage}{\newpage\tableofcontents\adcont{TABLE OF CONTENTS}}
\newcommand{\mychapters}{\addtocontents{toc}{\vspace{4mm}\hspace*{-12mm}CHAPTERS:\vspace{4mm}\par}\phantom{A}}

Comment: @ugur - Please post the LaTeX code in the body of your query, where it'll be far more likely to be seen than if it's tucked away in a comment.

Comment: \titlecontents{chapter}[15mm]{\addvspace{4mm}\bfseries\rmfamily}{\contentslabel{10mm}}{}{\titlerule*[4mm]{.}\contentspage}
\titlecontents{section}[24mm]{}{\contentslabel{9mm}}{}{\titlerule*[4mm]{.}\contentspage}
\renewcommand{\contentsname}{\vspace*{1mm}\begin{center}TABLE OF CONTENTS\end{center}\vspace{-16mm}}
\newcommand{\adcont}[1]{\addcontentsline{toc}{chapter}{\hspace*{-15mm}#1}} 
\newcommand{\tocpage}{\newpage\tableofcontents\adcont{TABLE OF CONTENTS}}
\newcommand{\mychapters}{\addtocontents{toc}{\vspace{4mm}\hspace*{-12mm}CHAPTERS:\vspace{4mm}\par}\phantom{A}}

Comment: Please post a **complete** compilable example **in** your question. This should start with `\documentclass` and end with `\end{document}`. Somebody who cuts, pastes and hits compile should produce the output in your (first) screenshot. Right now, I'm not even sure what you are posting. What is the relationship between the different code fragments?

Comment: \titlecontents{chapter}
[25pt] 
{}%
{\contentsmargin{10pt}     
    \thecontentslabel\enspace%
    \normalfont }
{\contentsmargin{10pt}\normalfont}      % unnumbered entry format{\titlerule*[1mm]{.}\contentspage}                 % filler-page format (e.g dots)
[]    
\titlecontents{section}
[50pt]         % left margin
{}%
{\contentsmargin{10pt}         % numbered entry format
    \thecontentslabel\enspace%
    \normalfont }
{\contentsmargin{10pt}\normalfont}      % unnumbered entry format
{\titlerule*[1mm]{.}\contentspage}                 % filler-page format (e.g dots)[]

Comment: @ugur **EDIT your question and post the code IN the question, formatted AS code.** It is currently unreadable, incomplete and fragmented.

Answer (score 1):

Just modify the given code to:

```
\titlecontents{chapter}
[25pt]         % left margin
{}%
{\contentsmargin{10pt}         % numbered entry format
    \textbf{\thecontentslabel.}\enspace%
    \normalfont }
{\contentsmargin{10pt}\normalfont}      % unnumbered entry format
{\titlerule*[1mm]{.}\contentspage}                 % filler-page format (e.g dots)
[]
```